# MATLAB excluding data outside 1 standard deviation

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, slice

I'm inexperienced with MATLAB, so sorry for the newbie question:

I've got a large vector (905350 elements) storing a whole bunch of data in it.
I have the standard deviation and mean, and now I want to cut out all the data points that are above/below one standard deviation from the mean.
I just have no clue how. From what I gather I have to make a double loop of some sort?

It's like: mean-std < data i want < mean + std

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the data is in variable `A`, with the mean stored in `meanA` and the standard deviation stored in `stdA`, then the following will extract the data you want while maintaining the original order of the data values:

```
B = A((A > meanA-stdA) & (A < meanA+stdA));
```

Here are some helpful documentation links that touch on the concepts used above: [logical operators](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/logicaloperatorselementwise.html), [matrix indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/digest/sept01/matrix.html).

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use the **Element-wise logical AND**:

```
m = mean(A);
sd = std(A);
B = A( A>m-sd & A<m+sd );
```

Also, knowing that: `|x|<c iff -c<x<c`, you can combine both into one as:

```
B = A( abs(A-m)<sd );
```

Comment: Your carets are backwards on line 3.

Answer (score 0):

Taking A as your original vector, and B as the final one:

```
B = sort(A)
B = B(find(B > mean-std,1,'first'):find(B < mean+std,1,'last'))
```

Comment: Whenever programming, keep in mind the features of the language you're working with.  Specifically with Matlab, try to avoid any looping if built-in funcitonality can cover it.  Great answer Lance.

Comment: When indexing in Matlab, one should try to avoid using find, unless you need to see the indices themselves.  Logical indexing is faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = x(x > mean-std);
y = y(y < mean+std);
```

should work.  See [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) for more details.  The FIND command is being used implicitly in the above code.

Comment: Actually, it's not using find.  It's using logical indexing, which is faster.